# For pytest with pytest-cov: how to specify parallel=True for coverage version >= 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

In [pytest-cov documentation](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) it says:

> Note that this plugin controls some options and setting the option in
>   the config file will have no effect. These include specifying source
>   to be measured (source option) and all data file handling (data_file
>   and parallel options).

However it doesn't say how to change these options.  Is there a way to change it (parallel=True)?
I want to change this because after coverage is upgraded from < 5 to latest (5.1) I got these:

```
Failed to generate report: Couldn't use data file '/path/to/jenkins/workspace/pr/or/branch/.coverage': no such table: line_bits
```

Note: using coverage < 5 do not have this problem

I have also tried adding *.coveragerc* with the following but still get the same issue.

```
[run]
parallel = True
```

The way it is run in jenkins:

```
pytest ./tests --mpl -n 4 \
   --junitxml=pyTests.xml --log-cli-level=DEBUG -s \
   --cov=. --cov-report --cov-report html:coverage-reports
```

Comment: This also seems to be a problem when using `unittest`, not just `pytest`.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to `pytest-cov` using `coverage combine`, which combines all coverage results: In parallel it mixes results from other runs, that may or may not be completed, and in any cases are irrelevant.

I think if you're having the issue, it may be because you're running multiple tests in parallel, like multiple versions of Python.

In which case it's easily solved by specifying a unique `COVERAGE_FILE` for each run, like:

```
export COVERAGE_FILE=.coverage.3.7
```

for the Python 3.7 run, an so on.

See: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/883#issuecomment-650562896